# Word document preview CRM 2011

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-word, dynamics-crm-2011, preview

I'm trying to create word preview for CRM 2011. I have some entity and I need to preview all attachment types. I've already made for images with Silverlight plugin. Now, I need to make .doc files preview. 
I registered plugin which get annotation's .doc attachment and get it byte array body.

What to do next?

How can I convert byte array to word document in stream, cause I can't save file from plugin (causing permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web resource using a html5 and/or flash to preview the document with this tool [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/)

Comment: Shanks, It's commercial project so I can't use trial version of FlexPaper. I can't buy it!